# React navigation show navigation history

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a case where I need to see the previous route, 
So I have 3 pages

1. A
2. B
3. C

**A** can navigate to **C**, and **B** can navigate to **C**. but in **C**, I have a condition that is based on the previous route, it will navigate to another page.

I'm also using Redux and Redux Sagas, so I'm navigating from the sagas using the **NavigationActions** like this

`yield put(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'C' }));`

Is it possible?

react-navigation 1.0.0-beta.11

react-native 0.46.1

node 6.9.1

npm 3.10.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reducer function you can have access to `routes` array.

```
function reducer(state: NavigationState, action: Action): NavigationState {
  const routes = state.routes; 
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you can access the routes. 
Managed to do it with something like this in my saga file.
```const getNavState = (state) => state.nav;```
Then using the select from redux-saga to get the state
```let navState = yield select(getNavState);```

And I could access the navState.routes, same as your solution but from the Saga.
Helped a lot, thank you.